# Links don't work after left click

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

On my site links in submenu (parent element - TERAPIA MANUALNA) do not work. The problem only appears after left click. Right click and 'open in new tab' works great. What cause the problem? I am using Divi template.

[My site](http://malnet.ovh/projects/gabinet_terapii/)

Comment: I thinks it's the problem of z-index of dropdown menu. try to play with it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: I think u have an issue in your javascript file (custom.js). Just comment those parts that u have call a click event on "<a href="#"></a> tag, just to see which one is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e) {
      $('menu-item-has-children').toggleClass("submenu-open"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This code is causing that the up level link "Terapia manualna" won't open on left click... It is because the call of "e.preventDefault();" stops the following of the link!

I can't find the problem with the submenu links that fast and easy, but I guess that this has something to do with this function:

```
(function($) {

function setup_collapsible_submenus() {
var $menu = $('#mobile_menu'),
top_level_link = '#mobile_menu > .menu-item-has-children > a';
$menu.find('a').each(function() {
$(this).off('click');

if ( $(this).is(top_level_link) ) {
$(this).attr('href', '#');
$(this).next('.sub-menu').addClass('hide');
}

if ( ! $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').length ) {
$(this).on('click', function(event) {
$(this).parents('.mobile_nav').trigger('click');
});
} else {
$(this).on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).next('.sub-menu').toggleClass('visible');
});
}
});
}
```

There again is a "prevent default" on all children of the submenu as far as i can see...

Try to change that and test again!